# JavaScript a Div with Indefinitely Generated Cells and a Horizontally-Locked Leftmost Column

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, scroll

I need to generate a spreadsheet using for loops, because the number of rows in the chart and the width of each row is indeterminate. So far, absolutely every example every search engine has thus returned in the past three weeks has not covered this. Either that, or there's some inherent difficulty in defining abstraction once one learns a specific amount of coding.

I have managed to make the leftmost column remain in place horizontally by using "position: sticky;" and "left: 0px;" properties/elements/tags/funyarinpas in its..."CSS". It'd also be really neat if "myDiv" could start out scrolled to the bottom of itself upon loading the page.

Here's my cruddy style, hashed together from weeks of training a cat to smash a brick on an old Gateway keyboard:

```
    .myDiv {
    width: 480px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: inline-block;
    outline: 1px dashed orange;
}

.myRowHeader {
    min-width: 25%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0px;
    text-align: right;
    z-index: 1;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    background-color: black;
    outline: 1px dotted green;
}

.myCell {
    min-width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    float: left;
    outline: 1px dotted cyan;
}
```

I want the dimensions and widths to stay like that. Henceforth, that "myDiv" will have to scroll vertically as well as horizontally. Oh, and eventually, "myDiv" will have to be placed into another div at some point. Here's some pseudo-JavaJavaJavacode:

```
   /* Initializes variables. */
    <set _target to "testChar">
    <set $levels to ["bad", "tepid", "good", "gooder", "swell", "neato", "bestest", "more most", "exquisite", "almost impressive"]>
    <set $fruit to {
         apple: 3,
         cherry: 3,
         coconut: 3,
         orange: 3,
         peach: 3,
         pear: 2,
     }>

    /* Generates the skill pyramid for the target character. */
    <div class="myDiv">
        <for _i to $levels.length; _i > 0; _i-->

                <div class="myRowHeader">
                    <print $maxLevel[_i]><print _i>
                </div>

                <for _j to 0; _j < $fruit.length; _j++>
                    <if $fruit[_j] is _i>
                        <div  class="myCell">
                            <print $fruit[_j]>
                        </div>
                    </if>
                </for><br>
        <</for>>
    </div>
```

Another reason why this code might be wrong apart from any lack of qualifications to even type coherent sentences let alone syntax is due to fatigue. Oh, it might be necessary to specify where and how all the solutions should be applied from a practical perspective.

Thank you for your time, and have a happy holidays.